# What is the best MYSQL or Maria DB data type to store JWT token?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5, jwt, sqldatatypes

I'm using the following technology stack

- Laravel 5.2
- MySQL

and for security I'm using JWT (JSON Web Tokens)

I was able to secure my applications using JWT.

I would like to store JWT token in mysql database.

> QUESTION **Which of the following data type is best to store JWT token in MySQL DB?**

1. VARCHAR
2. CLOB
3. TEXT
4. LONG TEXT

Comment: Isn't the point of a JWT that it doesn't need to be stored in the database?

Comment: @ceejayoz Refresh tokens can also be JWTs themselves and I believe one would need to store them in a data store.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As with anything else, the answer is "it depends".

First, you need to determine if storing the fully encoded JWT is the correct solution.  I tend to not store the JWT string and instead store the claims used to construct the JWT, which will save a ton of room in the database.

If you decide that storing the JWT is the correct method, then we can look at your options.

TEXT and LONGTEXT are just types of CLOB, so we can ignore that one.

TEXT and VARCHAR both have limits of 64kb, so anything above that will require LONGTEXT (or MEDIUMTEXT, which you didn't mention but is an option).

The difference between TEXT and VARCHAR is that VARCHAR is stored in the row but TEXT is basically a pointer.  VARCHAR will be faster if you are going to be reading the JWT often, but larger strings will cause each individual row to be larger, which will be a performance hit.

With as large as JWTs tend to be, I would say that TEXT is a pretty good choice to store JWTs in the database. If you are  absolutely confident that the JWTs will stay very small, then a VARCHAR may produce better read performance, but you would would be best to test with real world data to be sure.

If you need a field larger than TEXT is able to provide, then I would reiterate my recommendation to avoid storing the encoded JWT, but LONGTEXT is an option there.

Comment: I decided to take Michael's advice re: storing the claims data.  The "jti" field seems to be made for this -- http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#RegisteredClaimName

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example, I would suggest this for an 'encoded' base64 token:

```
TEXT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin
```

In general, JSON should be some size of `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` with `CHARACTER SET utf8` or `utf8mb4`.  (The `COLLATION` is likely to be irrelevant.)

`TEXT` is limited to 64KB; there is not much advantage in using a smaller `VARCHAR`.

Re: "`TEXT` is just a pointer"  -- Not quite correct.  In some `ROW_FORMATs` in InnoDB, either `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` may be a pointer to an extension to the row.  The action depends mostly on the `ROW_FORMAT`, not the datatype.